# Cannot change alternative symbol in exam2nops

Tags: r-exams

I've tried everything but can't seem to change the symbols for the answerlist items in `exams2nops`: I want to change them from

in the questions from:

[image: alph numbering in answerlist]

to upper case

[image: Alph numbering (upper case) in answerlist]

I've changed the LaTeX codes from the templates, and `exam2pdf` generates the uppercase one, but once I use `exam2nops`, the lower case one is used again.

Any help?

Comment: Does the answer below resolve your question? If not, please refine the question correspondingly. If it does, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `exams2pdf` you can change these via the `template = ...` used because this gives you the possibility to define your own format.

In `exams2nops`, however, the format is standardized so that it can be processed fully automatically. The template is fixed and cannot be changed as in `exams2pdf`.

But if you are determined to overrule the default, you can do so by re-defining the {answerlist} environment in the `header = ...` argument:

```
exams2nops("capitals.Rmd",
  header = "\\renewenvironment{answerlist}{\\renewcommand{\\labelenumii}{(\\Alph{enumii})}\\begin{enumerate}}{\\end{enumerate}}")
```

Note however that in this case the labels on the exam sheet (first page) are out of sync and still use: a, b, c, ...!

As the lower-case labels a, b, c, ... are widely used and easy to understand, it never seemed to be important enough to support other kinds of labels.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I'm generating questions for an IB class and they use capital letters. Some questions have images which include the options in them (capitalised), and the difference was bothering me. Thank you!

Comment: OK, good. Then please accept the answer here on StackOverflow (by clicking the check mark on the left of it) so that it is flagged as resolved.